# llenar un input apartir de datos de un option traidos con foreach

Tags: php

Excelente tarde quiero llenar un input de tipo hidden id="cdCliente" con los datos de un option que se carga de una base de datos alguien me podria apoyar, saludos

```
              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>

                <select class="form-control" id="seleccionarCliente" name="seleccionarCliente" required>

                <option  value="">Seleccionar cliente</option>

                <?php

                  $item = null;
                  $valor = null;

                  $categorias = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($item, $valor);

                   foreach ($categorias as $key => $value) {

                     echo '<option value="'.$value["id"].'">'.$value["nombre"].'</option>';

                   }

                ?>
                </select>

                <input type="hidden" id="cdCliente" name="cdCliente" >


              </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: Quieres cambiar el valor del input cada vez que se cambie la selección?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con `jQuery` se puede lograr de una manera muy sencilla. En el código comentado te dejo una pequeña instrucción.

```js
// Cada vez que cambie el select
$("#seleccionarCliente").change(function(){
  // a la variable x le asigno el value del select con id="seleccionarCliente"
  var x = $('#seleccionarCliente').val();
  // le asigno el valor de x al input con id="cdCliente"
  $('#cdCliente').val(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>
    <select class="form-control" id="seleccionarCliente" name="seleccionarCliente" required>
        <option  value="">Seleccionar cliente</option>
        <!--Ejemplos para mostrar el resultado, los puedes eliminar-->
        <option value="1">Cliente 1</option>
        <option value="2">Cliente 2</option>
        <?php
            $item = null;
            $valor = null;
            $categorias = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($item, $valor);
            foreach ($categorias as $key => $value) :?>
                <option value="<?= $value['id']; ?>"><?= $value['nombre']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach;
        ?>
    </select>
    <!-- cambiar type text por hidden -->
    <input type="text" id="cdCliente" name="cdCliente" >
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente repuesta gracias DjCrazy;                                                                  en esta parte var cdCliente = $('#seleccionarCliente').val();  intento darle un valor diferente del id o el nombre del cliente, en la base de datos tengo el id, nombre del cliente y precio; me gustaría darle el valor de la columna del precio var cdCliente = $('#seleccionarCliente').val(respuesta["precio"]); gracias hasta el momento tu código me ha servido saludos

Comment: Cambié el nombre de la variable para que no te confundas con la función del script de `jQuery`... si los precios están directamente relacionados con el cliente, le puedes asignar de una vez al `value` el campo del precio. Algo así: `<option value="<?= $value['precio']; ?>"><?= $value['nombre']; ?></option>`

Comment: @Java espero tu comentario si te funciona esta última sugerencia.

Comment: gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder lo había considerado de esa manera pero también necesito traer el ['id'] del cliente para guardarlo a la hora de generar la venta y el precio es para darle un precio preferencial algunos clientes de acuerdo a sus compras

Comment: @Java ok, en ese caso puedes traer el precio especial con `ajax`... Intenta hacerlo y si algo no te funciona te sugiero abrir una nueva pregunta ya que es un tema diferente al que se trata en la actual. De paso te invito a aceptar esta respuesta si satisfizo tu duda inicial.

Comment: gracias saludos